# Lightning Function Python

Tags: python, function, random, pygame

I am currently working on writing a function as part of a functions assignment.  I am using python 2.7.5 and pygame.  We are supposed to write a recursive function that draws lighting.  I am currently having an error with my code but I do not know what it is.  Here is my code:

```
from math import *
from pygame import *
from random import *

screen=display.set_mode((800,600))


def lightning(screen,x,y,size,ang):
    if size > 5:
        rang = radians(ang)
        x2 = x-size*cos(rang)
        y2 = y+size*sin(rang)
        draw.line(screen,(200,180,0),(x,y),(x2,y2))
        lightning(screen,x2,y2,size-randint(1,10),ang-randint(-20,10))
        lightning(screen,x2,y2,size-randint(1,10),ang+randint(-10,30))

lightning(screen,400,0,100,randint(60,100))
running=True
while running:
    for evt in event.get():
        if evt.type==QUIT:
            runnning=False
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    lightning(screen,400,0,100,randint(60,100))
    time.wait(500)

    display.flip()
 quit()
```

Currently, when I try to add another line of lightning (the "lightning(...)") it does not display any error in the shell and also does not display anything in the pygame window.  When I have only one line, the lightning functions properly.  I would just like to know where my error is and reasons to why it is causing the error.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe because you never actually quit the function? It's just looping and looping again.

Comment: Please format your python code according to PEP-8.

Comment: I suggest adding `print` statements inside `lightning()` and see what it prints while it is running.  If you can't see the output while it is running, write the printed statements into a log file and look at that after you run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `size=100` function `ligthning()` is call 800 000 to 3 500 000 times.

If you add another line of lightning it gives you even 7 000 000 calls.

Maybe You don't see result because it works too long. Try your code for smaller `size`.

My code to count `ligthning()` calls.

```
from math import *
from pygame import *
from random import *

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

def lightning(screen, x, y, size, ang, count):
    if size > 5:
        rang = radians(ang)
        x2 = x-size*cos(rang)
        y2 = y+size*sin(rang)
        draw.line(screen,(200,180,0),(x,y),(x2,y2))
        count = lightning(screen,x2,y2,size-randint(1,10),ang-randint(-20,10), count)
        count = lightning(screen,x2,y2,size-randint(1,10),ang+randint(-10,30), count)
    return count + 1

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

screen = display.set_mode((800,600))

#lightning(screen,400, 0, 100, randint(60,100))

running = True

while running:

    for evt in event.get():
        if evt.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        elif evt.type == KEYDOWN:
            if evt.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    print 'count: ', lightning(screen, 400, 0, 100, randint(60,100), 0)
    display.flip()

    #time.wait(500)

quit()
```

---

EDIT:

Theoretically `radint(1,10)` can always give `1` so you can always have `lightning(...,size-1, ...)` and for `size=100`it can give 2**95 calls.

2**95 = 39 614 081 257 132 168 796 771 975 168L